# Flutter remove border expansion tile

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i created an expansion tile and i cannot find a way how to remove the border or shadow of the box. Do you guys know the command?

here is a picture

https://gyazo.com/6dc133ca91071c0afeb65899688311aa

here is a picture, you can see it on the corner edge
sorry because it is long but this is the full expansion

```
ExpansionTile(
trailing: Text(''),
leading: Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 10.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 0.0),
    child: Image.asset(
        'images/food.png'
    )),
title: Row(
    children: < Widget > [


        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 0, left: 10, top: 15, bottom: 15),
                child: Column(textDirection: TextDirection.ltr, crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: < Widget > [



                    Container(
                        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, top: 7.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 3.0),
                        child: Text(
                            'Food System', textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 25,
                            ),
                        )),
                    Text(
                        'Customize the food system', textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(

                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 15,
                        ),
                    )

                ])),

    ], ),
children: < Widget > [



    Container(
        width: 300,
        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 0.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: new Container(


            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: < Widget > [
                Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: .0, right: 20.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text('Storage', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), ),
                Center(child: Column(children: < Widget > [
                    Container(
                        child: Column(children: < Widget > [
                            Text('2.4 KG left        -        7 Days', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                            Text('200 G / Meal  - 600 G / Day', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                        ], ),
                        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10.0),
                    )

                ], )),
                Container(
                    margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0, top: .0, right: 20.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    child: Text('Meal times', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)), ),
                Center(child: Column(children: < Widget > [

                    Text('1.   Breakfast   -   8:30 AM', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                    Text('2.   Lunch         -   2:00 PM', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                    Text('3.   Dinner        -   9:15  PM', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                ], ))
            ], ), )
    ),




    Container(
        height: 50.0,
        width: 300,

        margin: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topRight,
                    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    colors: [Color(0xff37b9ff), Color(0xff5d3afd)]),
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                            bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(40.0),
                                bottomRight: const Radius.circular(40.0),

                )
            ),
            child: Center(child:

                Text('Edit', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15))

                , )
        )
    ),
])
```

Comment: hi , can you please add your code ... we Correct that together ..

Comment: i posted it, i am sorry it is that long..

Answer (score 47, accepted):

this Color comes From Your App Theme and `dividerColor` ...
now You can add this Code in Your Theme

```
theme: ThemeData(
    dividerColor: Colors.transparent
  ),
```

or Use [Theme widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) with `Theme.of(context)` and change this value locally

```
Theme(
   data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
        child: ExpansionTile(
```

### full customization way

another way ... you can change every thing with this way(full customization)
copy the file from flutter sdk to your lib

how to find the file :

click + ctrl on class name

[image]

click on target icon at here

[image]

right click on show in Explorer

[image]

then you should

1. change the file name and copy this on your lib .
2. fix imports
3. change class name (very important) ( with right click and refactor)
4. finally use it !! :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, i really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Do you also know how can i remove this box at the end of the expansion tile? i think it is something with the trailing. When i add more text i get this error and i cannot center the items in the container. Here is a picture:
https://gyazo.com/c29329106dc5dcb162b71b5f41951b67

Comment: honestly I am not sure ... but I think you can use OverflowBox .. https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/flutter-using-overflowbox-widget-examples

Comment: another way is (I am sure about this) ... you can copy a ExpansionTile file from your sdk and Customize it (this is very easy)

Comment: i have no idea where to find it

Comment: "F:\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\expansion_tile.dart"

Comment: and i copy it in my app folder?

Comment: copy this to your lib folder and change ExpansionTile to MyExpansionTile (or what you want) and correct imports. (make sure you are change the class name)

Comment: from where are the imports? same destinasion as the expansiontitle?

Comment: i add an instruction.@AndreiMarin

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 97):

You can wrap it in a Theme widget and do like this:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData().copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
  child: ExpansionTile(
```

or if you're using custom **theme settings**, you can use `Theme.of(context)` instead of `ThemeData()` like this:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: ExpansionTile(
```

Comment: Give this person a Beer!

Comment: Another one from me too!

Answer (score 31):

Use the `shape` argument:

```dart
shape: const Border(),
```

Documentation say:

```dart
/// The tile's border shape when the sublist is expanded.
///
/// If this property is null, the [ExpansionTileThemeData.shape] is used. If that
/// is also null, a [Border] with vertical sides default to [ThemeData.dividerColor] is used
```

Comment: This is the easiest solution that does the work perfectly

Comment: This is the correct answer instead of adding theme and divider color as transparent

Comment: This is simple. Exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 10):

```dart
ExpansionTile(
    collapsedShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
         side: BorderSide.none,
    ),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
       side: BorderSide.none,
    ),
...
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: This remove the border when expanded and collapsed, which is what i want

Answer (score 9):

Just add this line inside expansiontitle

```
shape: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
```

Comment: This helped me remove the borders appearing around the tile after expansion. Thanks for this simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

**This solution is intended for people who've already set-up Project's Theme.**

The already existing answers provide a solution to wrap the `ExpansionTile` with `Theme` and pass it `ThemeData` but the problem with this way is it will override your app's theme and will change all values of app's `ThemeData` even when the value passed to it is only the `dividerColor`. This will change the theme to default theme of a Flutter app.

There are two ways:

1. **To change it locally only for the respective widget:** Wrap it with `Theme` but instead of default `ThemeData().copyWith()` as in above answers, change it your already existing theme data `YourThemeData().copyWith()`, this way it will follow your app's theme as:

   ```
    Theme(
      data: YourThemeData().copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
      child: ExpansionTile(
      ),
    );
   ```
2. **Globally, for every widget in the project:**

   So, if you're already using `ThemeModel` with `ThemeData` for dark and light mode, then, just add

   ```
    dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
   ```

   to your theme. To find out if you're using ThemeData already, then check your main file:

   ```
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeModel().lightMode,
      darkTheme: ThemeModel().darkMode,
      themeMode:
        mode.darkTheme == true ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
      home: Title(
        title: 'Your App name',
        color: DefaultColor,
        child: SplashScreen()),
    );
   ```

   See, `ThemeModel().lightmode` and `ThemeModel().darkMode` are two `ThemeData` in         which you've to add the aforementioned `dividerColor` line.

Answer (score 3):

**To remove border while expanding tile:**

```
Theme(
   data : ThemeData().copyWith(dividerColor: Colors.transparent),
   ExpansionTile(
              tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              children: [
                Text("Flutter Developer",
                    style: textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
              ],
              title: Text("Mobile",
                  style: textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))))
```

above code will help you to remove border from your expansion tile :)

**To Change trailing icon (Expansion tile Arrow) color:**

```
ExpansionTileTheme(
  data: ExpansionTileThemeData(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  iconColor: Colors.black,
  collapsedIconColor: Colors.black),
          child: ExpansionTile(
              tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              childrenPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              children: [
                Text("Flutter Developer",
                    style: textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
              ],
              title: Text("Mobile",
                  style: textTheme.headline1!.copyWith(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))))
```

Happy Fluttering!!

Answer (score 0):

Just using this package: [expansion_tile_group](https://pub.dev/packages/expansion_tile_group) . This package includes all parameters of `ExpansionTile`, so you can easy to move all current parameters to new one. After you import this package, using `ExpansionTileItem` widget to replace the `ExpansionTile`. After that, adding `isHasTopBorder` = `false` and `isHasBottomBorder` = `false`, now you are completely removing the default border of ExpansionTile.
Good luck to you

Answer (score 0):

```
shape: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0),
collapsedShape: Border.all(color: Colors.transparent, width: 0),
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?