# Is it possible to use Material Banner Widget without Actions?

Tags: flutter, widget, android-banner

I'm trying to use the [material banner widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialBanner-class.html) but a list of actions is required. The list of actions is causing the banner to look weird even when I place an empty container inside of the list.

Should I not be using the material banner widget since it requires a list when my design doesn't need a list of actions available? I want to use the widget since I can use these methods easily.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showMaterialBanner & ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).clearMaterialBanners();
```

If I shouldn't be using the widget, does anyone else have a good replacement for it?
Thank You.

Edit: I've added an image for reference.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw3hR.jpg
I want to get rid of the red area on the right side of the banner. I've tried setting the material banner's padding to padding: EdgeInsets.zero

Comment: please look at this answer and follow second way for Material Banner.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123839/flutter-remove-border-expansion-tile/64124471#64124471

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way but it's dirty: open the MaterialBanner widget and change everything you don't like in the code.

Below are the changes I made. After that, I'm passing any List of widgets as actions to the MaterialBanner, which is simply ignored.

[Changes to MaterialBanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNMmW.png)