# Flutter, material, remove faint line under DrawerHeader

Tags: flutter

The DrawerHeader widget produces a faint line below the DrawerHeader widget. How can I remove this? I've tried the decoration options and the only way I've found so far is to switch from a DrawerHeader to a custom widget, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

The following is code from the Flutter.dev guide, with the DrawerHeader color set to white, so the line is visible.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const appTitle = 'Drawer Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text('My Page!'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Text('Drawer Header'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 1'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Item 2'),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: It seems to be added from this line in the drawer_header.dart (std lib) file. Line 85. I don't see anyway to disable it.

```
        border: Border(
          bottom: Divider.createBorderSide(context),
        ),
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution. Just wrap your drawerheader widget in Theme widget and apply this data or just set transparent color in your `DividerThemeData` and Booom.

```
Theme(
 data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
  dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(color: Colors.transparent),
 ),
 child: DrawerHeader(child: YourWidget()) 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: simplified the following answer after finding out about the [**Theme** widget](https://youtu.be/oTvQDJOBXmM?t=130), which can be used to apply themes granularly to a sub-part of the UI.

### Problem Statement

A **DrawerHeader** is just a **Container** with a child **AnimatedContainer**. Both of those have a *decoration* property.

We can modify the *decoration* property of the child (since it receives the *decoration* we set to our DrawerHeader), but not that of the parent, inside of which the faint line is actually added as a **Divider** widget with a bottom border.

However, both the *color* & *width* of that border uses the *context*'s **DividerTheme** or **Theme** (in that order), which we can set via global or local themes.

### Solution

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71109638/3559724).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the DrawerHeader and place a container instead. It works the same way but without a line.

```
drawer: Drawer(
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: const Text('Drawer Header'),
                    height: 220,

                  ),

                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Item 1'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                  ListTile(
                    title: const Text('Item 2'),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

(I don't recommend it though. Try a different user interface widget. (Not Drawer)).

Answer (score 0):

to make the divider invisible, perhaps make the decoration transparent:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.transparent
)
```

May want to make sure you're on the latest version also.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I also modified the example at the following as per your suggestion, and the line is thicker and brighter. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/drawer

Comment: I added an EDIT to the original as I found the line in the std lib that is causing it to display. It may not be removable.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully work this below code

```
 child: DrawerHeader(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border(
              bottom: Divider.createBorderSide(context,
                  color: Colors.white, width: 0.0),
            ),
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

only add this command to your main page:

```
dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(color: Colors.transparent),
```

inside the ThemData, here is the the code:

```
theme: ThemeData(
        dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(color: Colors.transparent),
      ),
```

hope this is helpful.